# Win32 Draw Bitmap (e.g. SetDIBitsToDevice) draws wrong image for some random image dimension

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap

**General descriptions:**

As title described, I tried to draw an image (w*h) given an input array (char* [wx*hx*3], e.g. pixel1 blue, pixel 1 green, pixel 1 red, pixel 2 blue, .....). It outputs a correct drawing for some image size (e.g. w=196, h=196) but outputs wrong image for other dimension (e.g. w=174, h=174). This is totally random behavior.

**My win32 drawing implementation:**

This is my example input array, a pure red color image.

```
char* imgData = new char[w * h * 3];
    char* rData = new char[w * h];
    char* gData = new char[w * h];
    char* bData = new char[w * h];
    for (int i = 0; i < w * h; ++i)
    {
        rData[i] = 255;
        gData[i] = 0;
        bData[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < w * h; ++i)
    {
        imgData[3*i] = bData[i];
        imgData[3*i+1] = gData[i];
        imgData[3*i+2] = rData[i];
    }
```

How I draw image:

```
//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, unsigned, WORD, LONG)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.

//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    RECT rt;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rt);

    switch (message) {
            case WM_PAINT:
        {
                hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            BITMAPINFO bmi;
            CBitmap bitmap;
            memset(&bmi,0,sizeof(bmi));
            bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bmi.bmiHeader);
            bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = inImage.getWidth();
            bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -inImage.getHeight();  
                        // Use negative height.  DIB is top-down.
            bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
            bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
            bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
            bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = inImage.getWidth()*inImage.getHeight();

            SetDIBitsToDevice(
                            hdc, 
                            0,
                            100, 
                            inImage.getWidth(), 
                            inImage.getHeight(),
                            0,
                            0,
                            0,
                            inImage.getHeight(),
                            inImage.getImageData(), //imgData
                            &bmi,
                            DIB_RGB_COLORS);
                            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            }
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Other settings I am not sure if it is cause of the problem:

```
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX); 

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, (LPCTSTR)IDI_IMAGE);
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = (LPCSTR)IDC_IMAGE;
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, (LPCTSTR)IDI_SMALL);

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}
```

```
//
//PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   HWND hWnd;

   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }
   
   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}
```

Example 1 (solid color):

[174*174 incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eJlx.png)

[196*196 correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fW7r.png)

Example 2 (some shapes):

[450*450 incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8JzW.png)

[256*256 correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQrjg.png)

Comment: Bitmap file lines are padded to multiples of 4 bytes. 450*3 and 174*3 aren't multiples of 4. Very common beginner mistake with bitmap files.

Comment: Documentation of the requirement: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapcoreinfo says "The bits in the array are packed together, but **each scan line must be padded with zeros to end on a LONG boundary**"

Comment: I am a newcomer in this domain. Thanks for all of your explanation!